# Cannot load XSD since Java 7u40

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have the following code which is part of a method to load an XSD from a resource stream (i.e the XSD is a local resource):

```
        // Instantiate the registry of available DOM implementations.
        DOMImplementationRegistry registry = null;
        try {
            registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassCastException e) {
            LOG.fatal("Error instantiating DOM implementation registry", e);

            return null;
        }

        // Get the DOM implementation for "LS" as we need this to be able to pass an input stream for parsing.
        final DOMImplementationLS domLS = (DOMImplementationLS)registry.getDOMImplementation("LS 3.0");

        // Set up the input stream for input to the parser.
        final LSInput lsi = domLS.createLSInput();
        lsi.setCharacterStream(new InputStreamReader(input));

        // Load the schema from the input stream.
        final XMLSchemaLoader loader = new XMLSchemaLoader();
        final XSModel model = loader.load(lsi);
```

The last line where I attempt to create the XSModel always returns null for Java 7 Update 40+ but works perfectly for Java 7 Update 25 and earlier.

What could be the cause and is there a solution?

I am using Java 7 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.